# Components rendered on top of each other with GroupLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, grouplayout

I trying to learn how to use Java Swing's GroupLayout.

First of all I just want to make a grid made from JLabels.

The problem I'm having is that the JLabels are being rendered directly on top of each other (i.e. in exactly the same spot so that one obscures the other).

Below is my code for what **should** be 3 JLabels in a column:

```
layout.setHorizontalGroup(
    layout.createSequentialGroup()
        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(one)
            .addComponent(two)
            .addComponent(three))
);
layout.setVerticalGroup(
    layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(one)
        .addComponent(two)
        .addComponent(three)
);
```

How do I get the labels to be positioned correctly.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the vertical layout you are also building a parallel group which should be a sequential one instead (you wan't distinct rows and not all in one).

```
layout.setVerticalGroup(
    layout.createSequentialGroup()
    .addComponent(one)
    .addComponent(two)
    .addComponent(three)
);
```

Remark: For this example you also do not need the sequential group in the horizontal layout.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. I didn't understand why it worked, but now I think that I had misunderstood the difference between sequential and parallel groups. I simply thought that sequential groups defined the x axis and the parallel groups defined the y axis, but having reread the oracle tutorial, sequential can be in either direction depending on whether we are defining the Horizontal or Vertical group and parallel just places the components in the same space. So parallel groups place the component on the same level (in x or y axis) and sequential groups separates them.